# Key vault access policy for the existing storage account in terraform

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-storage-account, azure-rm

I try to assign the policy to Azure Key Vault for the existing storage account. The problem is that can't find how to get the UUID of the account(principal_id) which is required for assigning the policy. I tried to find the right attribute for data but it looks like it doesn't exist for the data object. So the question is how can I assign Key vault access policy for the existing storage account?

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "storage2" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = data.azurerm_storage_account.example.identity.0.principal_id

  key_permissions    = ["get", "create", "list", "restore", "recover", "unwrapkey", "wrapkey", "purge", "encrypt", "decrypt", "sign", "verify"]
  secret_permissions = ["get"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Key Vault Access Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault?view=azure-cli-latest#az_keyvault_set_policy)

An Azure storage account uses credentials comprising an account name and a key. The key is auto-generated and serves as a password, rather than an as a cryptographic key. Key Vault manages storage account keys by periodically regenerating them in storage account and provides shared access signature tokens for delegated access to resources in storage account.

User can use the Key Vault managed storage account key feature to list (sync) keys with an Azure storage account, and regenerate (rotate) the keys periodically. User can manage keys for both storage accounts and Classic storage accounts.

User can manage storage account with key vault  set policy by [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys-powershell) or [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys).

Comment: Thank for the answer, but I'm looking for a Terraform solution and not to do additional scripts with azure CLI or Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Below link gives you the information about how to create a customer managed key in terraform wherein creating a key vault policy is a part of it
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account_customer_managed_key

Universally Unique Identifiers (UUID) are assigned to the overall directory and each user individual account that exists in Azure Active Directory (AAD), whether the account was created in the cloud or was initially created on an Active Directory (AD) on-premises instance and was then synchronized to the cloud

with the above information UUID is nothing but the object id of the user that was available in the active directory. if you refer the below document you can able to find out the object id of the user from the portal
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/find-tenant-object-id

you can refer the below SO thread to create an object id using the terraform

[Terraform create a azure key vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64989203/terraform-create-a-azure-key-vault)

Comment: @Daniel M, if the above provided answer was helpful ? If so Could you please accept the answer as solution. This could help other community users who have similar query in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use:

```
data "azurerm_resources" "storage_account" {  
    type = "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"  
    name = "<your_storage_account_name>"
}
```

and if you're using a Managed Service Identity, the principal_id may be exposed there whereas it's not in the data.azurerm_storage_account resource...

I haven't tried it yet, so ymmv, but I have the same problem with finding the principal_id for existing WebApps that have an MSI, and the data resource for them doesn't expose the .identity properties either, so I plan to....